# How can I fix this error in c code for linked lists?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am receiving an error on Xcode when for my delete function for a single linked list in c and at this point im not sure why. The error im receiving is 
"malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeefbff5d8: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"

```
int delete (node ** list, int delete)
{
    node * current= *list;//declares current
    //stop at node that is one before i will need to delete (in this case iam deleting the 2node)
    if (*list != NULL)
    {
        node * temp= *list;
        temp = temp->next;
        free(list);
        *list=temp;

    }
    while (current->next->data != delete)
    {
        current=current->next;
    }
    node * temp;//Declares temp
    temp=current->next->next;
    free(current->next);//one after current free'd
    current->next=temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which free is the error message referring too? There are two and you haven't given a line number...

Comment: the error presents itself in the if statement at free(list);

Comment: In which case, you need to provide the calling code and the definition of node

Comment: Would you please complete the question.

Comment: I am not sure why you can't post the code which completes this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of things which is not clear or unnecessary

- Why you want to free the `free(list);` `list` is double pointer, if you free this `headpointer` of linked list will loose. after delete operation  How will `print/access` the list again if needed ?
- `list` is the `headpointer` which is holding the link and you didn't allocated any memory for list in `main()` or calling function so you can't free it. thats why error is

> pointer being freed was not allocated

If you want to `free` only then first you should do `free(*list)` and then `free(list)`

- From your code segment

  ```
  free(list); /* list is freed here */
  *list=temp; /* How will you access again *list */
  ```

As per my thinking your `if` block should be

```
if (*list != NULL) {
    node * temp= *list;
    temp = temp->next; /* temp holds 2nd node address & you need that only */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Your question was very unclear, for the next time please post all of the necessary code and explain the purpose of the function in a few line.

I guess what you are trying to do is to remove a specific item from a linked list according to the value of the parameter `data`.

From the site [learn-c](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists):

"
Removing a specific item
To remove a specific item from the list, either by its index from the beginning of the list or by its value, we will need to go over all the items, continuously looking ahead to find out if we've reached the node before the item we wish to remove. This is because we need to change the location to where the previous node points to as well.

Here is the algorithm:

1. Iterate to the node before the node we wish to delete
2. Save the node we wish to delete in a temporary pointer
3. Set the previous node's next pointer to point to the node after the node we wish to delete
4. Delete the node using the temporary pointer

There are a few edge cases we need to take care of, so make sure you understand the code. " 
Then they posted the code, I think you should go there and read the entire post.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a faulty logic plus obvious errors.
Once list is freed you have no right to access it again.

```
free(list);
*list=temp;
```

Managing the linked list is not difficult but it requires attention to details.

- When you delete the node in the list you have a responsibility to connect the nodes.
- If you delete the head you have a responsibility to move the head.
- If the head is the node you are looking for and this is the only node in the list than after removal that node has to be marked as `NULL`.

The test program below uses `struct node *find(struct node *start, int data)` function to find a node which matches your criteria and uses `delete` to delete it. All edge cases have been taken care of.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Basic simple single list implementation to illustrate 
// a proper deletion of the node which has a specfic data value.

// Node in List
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next; // pointer to next node
}node;

// List structure
typedef struct list {
    node* head;     // The entry point into a linked list.  If the list is empty then the head is a null reference. 
} list;

// Create list
list* list_create()
{
    list* new_list = malloc(sizeof(list));

    if(new_list == NULL)
        return NULL;        // protection

    new_list->head = NULL;  // If the list is empty then the head is a null reference.  no elements in the list 

    return new_list;        // return created new list
}

// returns newly created node
node* node_new(int data)
{
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate memory for the node 

    if (new_node == NULL)
        return NULL;                             // protection 

    new_node->data = data;                       // remember the data 
    new_node->next = NULL;                       // no next node

    return new_node;                             // return new created node
}

// The method creates a node and prepends it at the beginning of the list.
// 
// Frequently used names for this method:
// 
// insert at head
// add first
// prepend
//
// returns new head or NULL on failer

node* prepend_node(list* in_list, node* new_node)

{
   // Add item to the front of the in_list, return pointer to the prepended node (head)    

    if(in_list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(new_node == NULL)                         // problem, not enough memory
       return NULL;                              // in_list->head has not changed 

/* 
                 new_node      
                   |*| -->  NULL   
                   next        
*/       
    if(in_list->head == NULL)                    // if list is empty 
    {
        in_list->head = new_node;                // the new_node becomes a head   
    }
    else // list already have a head node
    {
/*
                |2|-->|1|-->NULL
                 ^ 
                 |
                 *
                head (2) (list pointer)

*/
        new_node->next = in_list->head;     // now, the new node next pointer points to the node pointed by the list head, see below:       

/* 
          new_node     
            |3|-->     |2|-->|1|-->NULL
                        ^  
                        |
                        *
                       head (list pointer)
*/          
        in_list->head = new_node;               // the list head has to move to new_node ( a new prepanded node)  

 /* 
          new_node       
            |3|-->  |2|-->|1|-->NULL
             ^       
             |           
             *           
            head (3) (list pointer)
*/         
    }

    return in_list->head;                       // we are returning pinter to new_node
}

// Print out list
void print_list(list* in_list)
{
    node* node;

    if (in_list == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (in_list->head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty!\n");
        return;
    }

   printf("List: ");

   node = in_list->head;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", node->data);

        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

struct node *find(struct node *start, int data)             // find p to be removed
{
    node* node;

    if (start == NULL)
        return NULL;

    node = start;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->data == data)
            return node; 

        node = node->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}


int delete(struct node **start, int data)
{
     struct node *p, *prev, *next, *to_free;

     if (start == NULL)                      // protection
        return 0;

     p = find(*start, data);                 // find p to be removed

     if (p == NULL)
        return 0;

     if (*start == NULL)
        return 0;                            // protection

     if(*start == p)                         // head == p
     {
        if((*start)->next !=NULL)
        {
            *start = (*start)->next;         // remember next 
            free(p);
            printf("Head removed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else // the only node
        {
            free(p);

            printf("Last node removed\n");
            *start = NULL;

            return 1;
        }
     }

     // p != start:

     next = *start; 

     while (next != NULL)
     {
        prev = next;                       
        to_free = next->next;                // candidate to be freed   

       if( to_free == p )
        {
            prev->next = to_free->next;      // connect nodes before deletion 

            free(to_free);                   // now free the remembered `next`
            to_free = NULL;                  // so it does not point to the released memory
            return 1;
        }

        next = next->next;                   // this node was not a match 
     } //while

    return 0; 
}

int main() {

   list* new_list = list_create();

   node *n1 = node_new(1);
   node *n2 = node_new(2);
   node *n3 = node_new(3);

  // list is empty
   print_list(new_list);

   prepend_node(new_list, n1);
   prepend_node(new_list, n2);
   prepend_node(new_list, n3);

  // list has 3 elements
   print_list(new_list);

   delete(&new_list->head, 3);  
   print_list(new_list);

   delete(&new_list->head, 1);  
   print_list(new_list);

   delete(&new_list->head, 2);
   // list has 2 elements
   print_list(new_list);

   printf("head: %p\n",new_list->head);

   print_list(new_list);

  free (new_list); // after deleting all elements, delete the list itself
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
List is empty!
List:  3 2 1
Head removed
List:  2 1
List:  2
Last node removed
List is empty!
head: (nil)
List is empty!
```